# How To Get variable name beside product name in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I created a new product with a variable type. With variable name 1 Year, 2 Year, 3 Year.

Examples in the cart, checkout, invoice and others. The variable name appears next to the product example name as illustrated.
For example As in the product order detail page, show the variable name next to the product name.

But do not change the original script file, change the script through function.

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V3T4.png)

Comment: how it is showing now ? below the product name ?

Comment: I want beside the product name